# How to select with an "xray" sort of effect?

Tags: selection-tools

I would like to press <kbd>RMB</kbd> and select not only the vertices/edge/faces on the front side, but the back side as well. I'm convinced this effect must be implemented, but I've been unable to find it or google for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable *Limit Selection to visible* in *3D view > Header*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually as I was writing this question, I found one method by pushing <kbd>Z</kbd> for wireframe mode.